# Best ASP.NET Websites for Sample Code / Code Projects

Tags: asp.net

I am new to .NET development.

Would you please let me know few best ASP.NET Websites for Sample Code / Code Projects?

Thank you & Regards.

Shravya.

Answer (score 5):

http://www.codeplex.com

CodePlex is Microsoft's open source project hosting web site.  It contains a myriad of projects or varying degrees of quality.  Checkout the "most downloaded" as those projects are the more popular ones.

Comment: Codeplex is really a great site;
asp.net/learn is equally lame (its mostly elemantry)

Answer (score 1):

http://www.codeproject.com/ is a good wesite. You can also take a look at the tutorials on http://asp.net

Answer (score 1):

http://www.xpode.com

Site having articles and examples

Answer (score 0):

I think this site is one of the best resources there is.  Most questions here either have a code example in the answer or point to a useful code example.

Answer (score 0):

the best enterprise web application would have to be DotNetNuke (DNN)
I have used it for years while at the New York Stock Exchange. Its an open source project that is maintained by a core set of developers and is a platform for Microsoft to showcase its latest and greatest .net technologies/ techniques such as all the various roles/ membership providers... unlike the rest of the answers here this is a single (big) application you can debug and learn a lot from and not a slew of mini projects or code sample... this will actually show you how to build a very scalable asp.net site for use in the real world.

you can download it here for free: http://www.dotnetnuke.com/

there is also a forum where you can post questions.

the big plus is all the modules (asp.net user controls) you can buy or build to use in your DNN websites.